# How I can send a user to a website, from a push notification in Android?

Tags: android, url, push-notification, browser

I recently installed the SDK for Android Push Notifications. I get to work. But what I would like is that when a user clicks on it, take you to a URL. Now I have set this down there. But when I open the APP is going directly to the browser. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
init();

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove startActivity(browserIntent) from onCreate method. onCreate method is executed when activity is started, not when user click on a notification.